# Is a multiple regression the proper test to answe my question and are the variables correct?

Tags: multiple-regression, modeling, interaction, interpretation

I have bird abundance (dependent variable) data for several hundred routes, and data describing the hectares of 17 different land use types (independent variable?) around those routes. I want to determine if bird abundance is significantly higher around any of the 17 different land use types. My plan to answer this question is to run a multiple regression in R. Does the syntax for this regression make sense? (Using my iPad right now so can’t provide snippet from R)

Model1<-lm(BirdAbundance~LandUseType1+LandUseType2+LandUseType3..+LandUseType17)

Are Thebes results from this test going to tell me HOW each land use type affects bird abundance, or just IF it does. In this case, should I be worried about interactions between different land use types?

Thanks in advance

Comment: First, R (or any software) will code the independent variable for you.  You can choose different parameterizations. Second, whether you want linear regression or something else depends on how bird abundance is measured. You might want some form of count regression.

Comment: Abundance was originally measured as number of birds observed within a 1 km buffer of each route, but for several years. I averaged the abundance across all years, so that there’s only one abundance value for each route. Say I do decide to use a multiple regression, I will get a P-value that tells me IF the affect of x on y is significant,  it h

Comment: ... but how will I know HOW x affects y?

Comment: The p value does NOT tell you if x affects y.  In fact, in an observational study like this, you can't attribute causation, but a p-value wouldn't tell you this even in an experiment.  You learn about the relationship between x and y via all the output of a regression and also via graphs and also via thinking about it using substantive knowledge.